# Parse username/password login error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement an error that shows up when the username and password don't match with the data on Parse. When I try logging in with a username and password that does not exist in the Parse core data, my application still segues to the next View Controller and then displays the error. Is there anyway I can fix this? Below is a screen shot of the code where the user can type in their username password. What happens is that when I try and type in a username and password that doesn't exist, it still segues and then displays the error message.

```
class logInViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()



func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    var errorMessage = "Please try again later"


    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password")

    }
    else{


        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()



            if user != nil {

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("log in", sender: self)


            } else {

                if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    errorMessage = errorString

                }

                self.displayAlert("Failed Login", message: errorMessage)
                print("uh oh")
            }

        })


    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code, include the actual code as text

Comment: `and then displays the error. ` - what error?

Comment: What's the errorString/message?

Comment: @luk2302 
it segues to the next view controller and the error message is "invalid login parameters"

Comment: Are you sure you didn't connect the segue to the button so that the segue is called regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the logic in your completion block - check for an error first, and only if there is no error, the proceed with the login process:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    if error != nil {
        if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {
                errorMessage = errorString
        }
        self.displayAlert("Failed Login", message: errorMessage)
            print("uh oh")
    } else {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("log in", sender: self)   
    })
```

Comment: I agree with this answer!